# Widening a Data Frame with multiple variables and id columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to widen data with multiple ID columns and Value columns. Below is an abstract of the code I am working with. Each row in  data frame corresponds to the performance of one team marked under the "Team" column, at a specific point in time. My main goal is to be able to align the stats for each of the teams with their opponents.

Here is the code to recreate the df:

```
df <- tribble( 
  ~MatchDate, ~"H/A", ~Team, ~Opponent, ~AvgScorePer3, ~AvgPointsPer3, ~AvgStrikesPer3, 
  "01/01/2020", "H", "Team 1", "Team 2", 3, 6, 10, 
  "02/01/2020", "A", "Team 1", "Team 3", 4, 7, 11, 
  "03/01/2020", "H", "Team 1", "Team 4", 5, 8, 14, 
  "01/01/2020", "H", "Team 2", "Team 1", 4, 10, 10,
  "02/02/2020", "H", "Team 2", "Team 4", 5, 7, 9, 
  "01/01/2020", "A", "Team 3", "Team 5", 4, 4, 7, 
  "02/01/2020", "A", "Team 3", "Team 1", 2, 3, 4, 
  "02/01/2020", "H", "Team 4", "Team 2", 3, 2, 3,
  "03/01/2020", "H", "Team 4", "Team 1", 4, 3, 5, 
  "01/01/2020", "A", "Team 5", "Team 3", 2, 6, 2
  )
```

The code below is an example of what I am trying to achieve, which will allow me to calculate differences between key stats.

```
df <- tribble (
  ~MatchDate, ~"H/A", ~Team, ~Opponent, ~AvgScorePer3Team, ~AvgPointsPer3Team, 
  ~AvgStrikesPer3Team, ~AvgScorePer3Opponent, ~AvgPointsPer3Opponent, ~AvgStrikesPer3Opponent, 
  "01/01/2020", "H", "Team 1", "Team 2", 3, 6, 10, 4, 10, 10,
  "02/01/2020", "A", "Team 1", "Team 3", 4, 7, 11, 2, 3, 4,
  "03/01/2020", "H", "Team 1", "Team 4", 5, 8, 14, 4, 3, 5,
  "01/01/2020", "H", "Team 2", "Team 1", 4, 10, 10, 3, 6, 10,
  "02/02/2020", "H", "Team 2", "Team 4", 5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 
  "01/01/2020", "A", "Team 3", "Team 5", 4, 4, 7, 2, 6, 2,
  "02/01/2020", "A", "Team 3", "Team 1", 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 11,
  "02/01/2020", "H", "Team 4", "Team 2", 3, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 
  "03/01/2020", "H", "Team 4", "Team 1", 4, 3, 5, 5, 8, 14, 
  "01/01/2020", "A", "Team 5", "Team 3", 2, 6, 2, 4, 4, 7 
)
```

So far I've looked at pivot_wider, reshape and dcast but can't produce the correct outcome. I keep ending up with far more variable columns than I expect as the new columns take on the names of existing teams!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing a self join.

```
left_join(
  df,
  df,
  by = c("MatchDate" = "MatchDate", "Team" = "Opponent", "Opponent" = "Team"),
  suffix = c("Team", "Opponent")
)
```

In your example I believe the match between Teams 4 and 2 has inconsistent dates between the top and bottom record.

Comment: I've been thinking about this entirely from a restructuring point of view... completely missed left_join() as the solution! Thanks for helping me see the forest for the trees.